# SSRS Multi Groups Using Parameter in Expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, parameter-passing, grouping, reportbuilder

In Report Builder, I have a report with many parameters, three of the parameters are @DateFrom, @DateTo, @Check

The query from the Main dataset gives this result with 3 columns: Name, Check, ExpiryDate.

```
Name    Check   ExpiryDate  
A        Y      05/01/2016  
B        N      06/10/2017  
C        Y      08/15/2017  
D        N      08/20/2017  
E        Y      09/05/2017  
F        N      10/20/2018
```

I need to group the report into 3 groups based on the parameter values, 
For example, the user runs the report would enter: @DateFrom = 08/1/2017  @DateTo: 08/31/2017
=> The report should look like below:

Group Current Range ExpiryDate  [(ExpiryDate >= @DateFrom and ExpiryDate <=@DateTo)  and Check = @Check ]

```
C        Y      08/15/2017  
D        N      08/20/2017
```

Group Before Range ExpiryDate and Check = 'Y'  [(ExpiryDate <= @DateFrom) and Check = 'Y']

```
A        Y      05/01/2016
```

Group After Range ExpiryDate and Check = 'Y' [(ExpiryDate >= @DateTo) and Check = 'Y']

```
E       Y       09/05/2017
```

In the tablix using the Main dataset (only one tablix in the report), there is one RowGroup named 'Details'

I read lots of arcticles and I tried many ways, but nothing worked as I could not find the right way I guess.  Will you be able to help?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create another group is to modify the SQL and add another column with your grouping logic.

```
SELECT
  ....,
  CASE 
    WHEN ExpiryDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND Check = @Check 
    THEN 'Current' 
    WHEN ExpiryDate <= @DateFrom AND Check = 'Y'
    THEN 'Before'
    WHEN ExpiryDate >= @DateTo AND Check = 'Y'
    THEN 'After'
  END as MyGroup,
  ...
FROM ...
```

so that you can create a parent group inside your tablix with the new custom grouping field.

OR if the SQL is very complex or you are using a shared dataset/stored procedure, then add a group to the SSRS tablix and specify a custom expression with similar logic using the SWITCH construct.

Edit, adding parameters to the SQL CASE

```
CASE
  WHEN expirydate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND [check] IN @check
  THEN 'Current'
  WHEN expirydate <= @FromDate AND [check] = 'Y' 
  THEN 'Before'
  WHEN expirydate >= @FromDate and [check] = 'Y'
  THEN 'After'
END as MyGroup
```

Note that check is only surrounded by square brackets because it's a reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: Excellent! thank you so much, I will try that immediately and will report back asap.

Comment: Hi Pete,  I tried your way and it worked if I hardcoded the CASE statement.  However, if I changed the script into real parameters, and put into the dataset query, ran the report I got error 'End of Statement is expected'.   I am not sure if I can post it here or I will have to create another matter. I will post it here in case you will help :)  This CASE statement is in the SELECT:  I do not know how to align them, sorry.

Comment: CASE 
     WHEN ( (ExpiryDate BETWEEN '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) &"' 
                       AND   '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!DateTo.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy"))   &"' 
           )
            AND     Check IN ('" & Join(Parameters!Check.Value,"','") & "') 
         ) THEN 'Current' 
    WHEN ((ExpiryDate <= '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!pFromDate.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) & "')  AND  Check = 'Y')  THEN 'Before'
    WHEN ((ExpiryDate >= '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!pFromDate.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) & "')  AND  Check = 'Y')  THEN 'After'     
   END as MyGroup

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much for looking into this.  It is PL/SQL Statement, and the CASE is in SELECT Statement.  Plus, the SSRS/Report from Report builder parameter is to be included in this CASE.  I used @check at first to make the case simple, and to ask for the logic of how to do this.  Then when I applied your logic , which is very helpful, I need to add the parameter values in.  Anyway, it is now working properly.  I thank you very much for your help again :)

Comment: answered.  much appreciated :)